# How to add fadein effect to lazyloader

Tags: javascript, fadein

I have a lazyloader for the images on my site. Here's the JS:

```
$("img[data-src]").responsivelazyloader();

$("body").on({ ajaxStop : function(){ $("img[data-src]").responsivelazyloader(); }});
```

It works, but the images just pop in, is there a way to make them fadein on load so it's all a little smoother? Here's one of the URLs where you can http://helloarchie.blue/posts/fashion-friday-be-like-the-cool-kids-026

Comment: What you may need to do is check for an event which is fired off by lazyloader and then attach to that, so basically when lazyloader fired "loaded" event put an event listener for that and then run the jQuery fadein function

Answer (score 0):

From Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery, see the fadeIn demo here 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

The implementation

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn"
});
```